# Zapier or Do-It-Myself?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, zapier, feedly

I am building a site that requires syncing into the [Feedly API](https://developer.feedly.com/) and I am trying to figure out the best way to do that.  On the one hand, I can do it myself -- i.e., go through the api docs and integrate it into my vuejs site.

On the other hand, I could use a service like [Zapier](https://zapier.com/apps/feedly/integrations) -- which will automate the task for me.

I am wondering what are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach.

**Please Note:** I am NOT looking for opinions as to whether or not someone likes zapier or thinks that coding by hand is always better, etc.  Rather, I'm looking for technical, factual benefits of each approach.

Thanks.

Comment: yeah I'd say lose the middle man, and go straight to feedly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really, it comes down to time, but here are a few things I have found that stand out the most:

**Pros**

-Ease of Use

-Connect your API in a matter of minutes

-Fairly limitless in number of concurrent connections and actions

-Customer service will try VERY hard to help solve any issue you have, even if that means looking over your JavaScript.

**Cons**

-You have a monthly fee

-You may end up building your own zap in the dev platform as some function was not included.

-You depend on a third party for uptime (however this is more  and more the case now days)

-Only as secure as you or Zapier makes it.

If this is a long term project and you don't plan to do anything more than a single call, then just build it yourself. However, if you lack experience in API's or are currently pressed for time then I'd toss it on Zapier.